# Error 500 returned only by IPN Paypal simulator, manual checking OK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, paypal, paypal-ipn

In my ASP MVC 2 project exists Paypal support, but server(application?) didn't accept IPN which should be sended as POST message. First I try to use IPN simulator and it's always return error 500.

Strange is, that my own testing script which send some form data to specify defined action for IPN works! At least I deleted all function code from IPN controller/action and let only simple logging and action is finished by: `return Content("some result text");`

I read some log from IIS, but I found only this:

```
Thread information:
Thread ID: 10 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace: at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SetControllerFactory>b__4()
```

It's really interesting, that my own testing scripts sending data as IPN are working, but Sandbox IPN simulator not.
Thanks for any advice or tip

Comment: I've got a similar problem, still waiting on a response from paypal. Will post when/if it comes.